# How to run Untrusted, Third-party code safely?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

mates. I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application like Hackerrank / Leetcode etc. It provides a set of problems and the user has to solve these problems on his machine and then submit the source code. The app will support solutions in C#, Java, C++ and Pascal. Everything was nice until I realised there is no security.

Here is how my application works:

1. The user submits his source-code to the server (program.cs, main.cpp etc)
2. The server compiles the code. If an executable in created, the app thinks that "Everything is Ok and we can run this program.exe / main.exe guy".
3. The server runs the .exe file for N times, where N is the number of tests for each problem. Then it compares the output of the .exe file with the correct output for that specific test case.

The problem is that I can't find a way to run that code safely. The user can submit some malicious code. The server will 100% run it. What to do?

Initially I've runned the .exe this way

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = (.exe file path goes here)
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
//Send the imput, get the output
p.WaitForExit();
```

Then I've tried to use SandBox.

```
AppDomain ap = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ProgramEXE",null);
string assemblyPath = (.exe location);
ap.ExecuteAssembly(assemblyPath, Imput);
AppDomain.Unload(ap);
```

Maybe I have to give a set of permissions, But how to do that? How to stop the program if it is malicios, How to run it in a Virtual Machine or something? Just give me a hint, please.

For example, if the untrusted code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TurnOffPcProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Code that will turn your PC off.

            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process.Start(psi);
        }
    }
}
```

The server will run it and will turn itself off (Lol).

If you know a way how to solve this problem I will be grateful. If you got some documentation about this, send it here.

I'm looking for a way on how to restrict executable's abilities, how to say to him that "No-no, you are a bad guy, you want `System.IO.Directory.Delete(@"C:\Temp", true);` that is not ok. I won't run you. "

Or maybe to create a closed environment and say to him "Do whatever you want, you can't damage anything."

Please, give me some hints on how to get out of this problem, some documentation, some examples, some code, whatever you got is welcomed <3. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is - you can't (easily). Some kind of restriction of user rights, or sandboxing, or spinning up independent machines, can reduce the blast radius. But if you let someone else's code run on your machine - well they can do anything that that account can do. https://www.quora.com/How-does-HackerRank-securely-sandbox-code-that-runs-on-their-system and https://dotnetfiddle.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/282670-restrictions may be worth a read.

Comment: Would using AWS Lambda be an option?

Comment: As an option consider running solutions inside of docker containers.
For a small application it will still put a significant overhead for building an image each time the solution is submitted, so I bet this solution is not the best and static analysis may give better result.

Comment: What do you mean by "Statis analysis"? I though about creating a filter that will go through the source code and analyse each word and if there is something suspect like "Directory.Delete" or "Process.Start();" then don't run the .exe but This is too primitive.

Comment: White or black listing of code patterns will not be enough, you will need the sandbox approach where you limit the actual access the executable has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, If you want to have full control over how the code runs, you have to build your own compiler, but if you just want to run SAFELY a piece of code - There are plenty of APIs out there who are willing to do your job, both free and paid, so you don't have to worry about security and all that stuff.

I ended up using this absolutely amazing API - https://ce.judge0.com

Strengths:

1. A  lot of supported languages
2. You don't have to worry too much about security (kinda)
3. It returns a lot of information about the solution (stdout, time, memory etc.)

Weaknesses:

1. Nope.